# Align items within an li not li within an ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[image]
[image]

I am trying to align the love heart below the 'A' without much luck, I have tried padding but it affects the li which fit nicely.

```
<li class="dropdown-link link-menu-item">                                                                                                    
    <a href="/academic-diaries.htm">Academic Diaries</a>                                                                                                       
    <i class="fa fa-heart orange"></i>                                                                                                
</li>

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xo9y31uk/ - I cant get it to mimic what I am seeing. Seems to be doing it right on jsfiddle

Comment: Make the li `position:relative` and the `.fa` `position:absolute`, then use `left` and `bottom` to move into place?

Comment: Clare would you mind creating a fiddle? It will be easier to assist you then... jsfiddle.net thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` to include the heart in the line. Span is a way to have a separate element but include it inside another.

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown-link link-menu-item">    
    <span class="fa fa-heart orange"></span>   
    <a href="/academic-diaries.htm">Academic Diaries</a>
</li>
```

For a demo click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/coozin/8cqqfvra/)

Comment: i need the heart to be after the link not before. I've tried span and it still produces the same issue

Comment: hmm... Idk I solved it just by moving the span after the "a" tag [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coozin/8cqqfvra/2/)